# Check if name contains only alphabet

Tags: c

I have a problem.

```
int main ()
{

    char name[100];

    do
    {
        printf("Input name : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", name);
        fflush(stdin);
    }while() // I don't know what to put here
}
```

The problem is how to loop "input name" if my input is not all alphabet.  For example, if I input "steve1" then it will ask for name again; if i input "Steve" then it will not loop.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` does not make any sense and is an error. One is assuming you wish for the Russian alphabet

Answer (score 1):

Write a separate function and use it in the loop condition. For example

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

int valid_name( const char *name )
{
    while ( *name && isalpha( ( unsigned char )*name ) ) ++name;

    return *name == '\0';
}

//...

do
{
    //...
} while ( !valid_name( name ) );
```

Comment: I don't quiet understand where to put that. Could you elaborate? Sorry I'm still beginner at this

Comment: @DonnyAvaris Place the function definition before main.

Comment: That should give a warning for casting away `const`. Not only there is no reason to, but I also don't see why you cast at all.

Comment: I didn't try this one, but for similar code, I get of course. Maybe not with vanilla options, but these are not recommended anyway, less for beginners. But even without the warning, there is just no reason for the cast, if you use the correct types. (and I don't refer to the statements outside a function, which I know you are aware of).

Comment: `isalpha( ( unsigned char )*name )` - Is the cast required?